# Error al momento de loguear, PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, php7, php5

estoy realizando un sistema y me presenta un error al entrar al login, el cual es

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo de conexion

```
<?php 
$server="localhost";
$username1="root";
$password="";
$database="onexamdb";
$con=mysql_connect($server,$username1,$password);
if(!$con)
  
  die( "Not connected") or mysql_error();
mysql_select_db($database);   

?>
```

Y este es el codigo que utilizo para hacer login

```
<?php
session_start();
include("connect.php");
if(!empty($_POST["login"])) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usertbl WHERE email='" . $_POST["email"] . "' and password = '".($_POST["password"])."'");
    $row  = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if(is_array($row)) {
    $_SESSION["userid"] = $row['uid'];
    $_SESSION["email"] = $row['email'];
    $_SESSION["fname"] = $row['fname'];
    $_SESSION["lname"] = $row['lname'];
    $_SESSION["file"] = $row['file'];
     header("Location:index.php");
    }
    
}
?>
```

No se exactamente porque sale ese error, soy algo nuevo en php, si alguien me ayuda porfa

Comment: Seguramente esa función ya no existe en la versión PHP que estes usando. El tutorial o curso que estas siguiendo debe ser muy antiguo. Reemplaza todos los `mysql_` que veas por `mylsqi_` y seguramente te funcionará algo mejor para salir del paso.

Comment: Ya los cambie pero me sigue generando error

Comment: ¿el mismo error o cual?  No estoy delante de tu monitor y no puedo verlo... dame pistas por favor :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como lo indicaban antes, la versión ha cambiado y la función correcta (que conozco) es "myslqi_".  Intenta usar la siguiente estructura:

```
$conection = mysqli_connect($tuhost, $tusuario, $tucontrasena, $tuDB);
$consulta = mysqli_query($conection,"select * from usuarios");

while($resultadoConsulta = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)){
   $_SESSION["atributo"] = $resultadoConsulta["campo"];
   #Este while es porque para recuperar los resultados de la consulta, 
   #aun asi sea solo uno, debes usar el ciclo para recorrer fila por 
   #fila
}
```